# Una lista de listas en Racket, obtener car de una lista solamente

Tags: lista, scheme

intento generar una lista de listas en Racket, para lo cual tengo la siguiente función:

```
(define (listaUsuario . usuario) usuario)
```

Por lo que si uno dos listas queda lo siguiente:

```
(define usuario1 (usuario "username1" "password1" 1 0))
(define usuario2 (usuario "username2" "password2" 1 0))
(define usuario3 (usuario "username3" "password3" 1 0))

(define stackUsuario01 (listaUsuario usuario1 usuario2))

>>
'(("username1" "password1" 1 0) ("username2" "password2" 1 0))
```

Pero al unir mas de dos listas, el car me queda con los primeros dos elementos es decir:

```
(define stackUsuario02 (listaUsuario stackUsuario01 usuario3))
(car stackUsuario02)
(cdr stackUsuario02)

>>
'((("username1" "password1" 1 0) ("username2" "password2" 1 0)) ("username3" "password3" 1 0))
'(("username1" "password1" 1 0) ("username2" "password2" 1 0))
'(("username3" "password3" 1 0))
```

¿Como puedo evitar tener dos listas en el car de stackUsuario02?, para facilitar la lectura de esta lista de listas.
Cabe destacar si agrego mas listas mediante la función listaUsuario, el car tendrá mas listas todavía. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: racket tiene la func flatten https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Flist..rkt)._flatten)) ``` ```

Answer (score 0):

### Solución:

1. Define `flatten` (no esta definido en Scheme, pero puedes utilizar lo saqué de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387583/writing-flatten-method-in-scheme)):

   ```
   (define (flatten x)
     (cond ((null? x) '())
           ((pair? x) (append (flatten (car x)) (flatten (cdr x))))
           (else (list x))))
   ```
2. Agrega `flatten` a tu definición de `listaUsuario`

   ```
   (define (listaUsuario . usuario) (flatten usuario))
   ```

---

### Explicación:

Tu *problema* se resume en aplanar una lista pues cuando haces una función del tipo:

```
(define (f . params) params)
```

Tienes que `params` es una lista de cualquier forma, por ejemplo si tenemos:

```
(f 1 2 3)        ; regresa: '(1 2 3)
(f 1 (f 2 3))    ; regresa: '(1 (2 3))
(f 1 (list 2 3)) ; regresa: '(1 (2 3))
```

Pues la serie de elementos después de `f` se trata como una lista, pero si usamos [`flatten`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387583/writing-flatten-method-in-scheme) podemos aplanar cualquier lista para dejarla como una lista de 1 sola dimensión como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
> (flatten (list 1 (list 2 3) 4))
'(1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo quiero que los datos referentes a un usuario sigan agrupados en una lista. Muchas gracias de todas maneras!!